# Spring JAX-WS- using Custom HandlerResolver to add dynamic header

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I am using a spring configuration like this to add a CustomHandler. It is working fine.  As per  [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html?is-external=true#setHandlerResolver) - **customHandlerResolver is called once per proxy**.

Here lies the issue. I need to add a dynamic security token header for each SOAP request and since the handler is called only once, my token expires after certain time, I am not able to set a refreshed token.

```
   <bean id="myServicePort" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="org.my.myService" />
        <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="classpath:wsdl/mysoap.wsdl" />
        <property name="namespaceUri" value="http://services.mycom.org" />
        <property name="serviceName" value="OrderService" />
        <property name="endpointAddress" ref="OrderEndPoint" />
        <property name="handlerResolver" ref="customHandlerResolver"/>
   </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said HandlerResolver is called only once, no matter what the scope of the bean is. I used  CXF - org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean as I get more control on bean creation, unlike the above Spring proxy where Spring itself creates the proxy.

```
 <bean id="proxyFactory"
    class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceClass" value="org.my.myService"/>
    <property name="address" value="http://localhost:9002/HelloWorld"/>
  </bean>
```

In my client code

```
//Set a handler 
proxyFactory.setHandlers( Arrays.asList((Handler) new TokenHandler(Token)));
OrderService orderServicePort=  (myService) proxyFactory.create();

//Call service method, as SOAP message has desired dynamic header
orderServicePort.getXXX()
```

This works perfectly and is less verbose than my initial spring config

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using bean scope prototype.

```
<bean id="myServicePort" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean" scope="prototype">
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="org.my.myService" />
    <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="classpath:wsdl/mysoap.wsdl" />
    <property name="namespaceUri" value="http://services.mycom.org" />
    <property name="serviceName" value="OrderService" />
    <property name="endpointAddress" ref="OrderEndPoint" />
    <property name="handlerResolver" ref="customHandlerResolver"/>
```

Comment: I tried that but the customHandleResolver method is only called once. I even made the customHandlerResolver as prototype. still same behavior.